# Show that $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\dotsb+ \frac{1}{n}$ is not a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $$
> a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{n} 
> \quad (n \in \mathbb{N}).
> $$
>   Show that $a_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence even though 
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}  - a_n = 0
> $$
>   (Therefore $a_n$ does not have a limit).

Comment: It's technically not forbidden to have spaces in function names (proofs aren't written in a programming language after all) but it's pretty confusing.

Comment: sorry about that I really dont know how to type in Latex

Comment: thxs i fixed it

Comment: Methinks that instead of $a\sub n$ you want $a_n$.

Comment: yes that would be it

Comment: You can probably find thousands of hints under the name "harmonic series" for this particular series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the *definition* of Cauchy sequence to show the sequence $(a_n)$ is not Cauchy.

Let $\epsilon=1/2$. We will show that there does not exist an $m$ such that for any $n\gt m$, we have  $|a_n-a_m|\lt \epsilon$.

For let $m$ be given, and let $2^k$ be the smallest power of $2$ that is $\gt m$. Let $n=2^{k+1}-1$. Then
$$a_n-a_m\ge \frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k}+1}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}\gt \frac{1}{2}.$$
The fact that the above sum is $\gt \frac{1}{2}$ follows from the fact that the sum has at least $2^k$ terms, each $\gt \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$

The fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$ is clear, since $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: why was epsilon chosen to be 1/2?

Comment: @mathrajova For convenience. This argument would work for any $\epsilon<\frac12$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Showing it doesn't converge (specifically that it goes to infinity) would help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/575220)

Comment: @Ramiro: It is an answer. Not an overly helpful answer, mind you, but....

Comment: SORRY everyone I added the word "hint", I forgot that's required.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/575232)

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis sorry I understood hints were well-accepted on math.SE?

Comment: @djechlin Certainly - but write them as a comment to the question, not as an answer.

Comment: It's not that what you said is invalid- its more that you should elaborate more if it is an answer, else keep it in the comments.

Comment: @Math1000 no, this has been discussed http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10589/79767

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis no, please see meta post I just linked.

Comment: Ah. I suppose you're right then- sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $e^x\ge 1+x$ and thus also $e^{-x}\ge 1-x$ one gets
$$
-\ln(1-x)\ge x \ge \ln(1+x)
$$
Now set $x=\frac1n$ to get
$$
\ln(n)-\ln(n-1)\ge\frac1n\ge\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)
$$
The left and right terms are telescoping in sums, so
$$
\ln(n)-\ln(m)\ge\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1k\ge\ln(n+1)-\ln(m+1)
$$
Since $\ln(n)\to\infty$, this shows that the sequence of partial sums can not be Cauchy.